# Capturing more helpful exception / diagnostic when using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, exception, logging, lambda

Much as I love lambda expressions / LINQ in C# I seem to come up with this same kind of issue from time to time, and would like some pointers on how best to handle the following type of scenario.

The following code is purely for example and will hopefully demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class Program
{
    public class Demo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Val { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Val { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
            List<Demo> list = new List<Demo> { 
                new Demo { Name = "First", Val = "1" }, 
                new Demo { Name = "Second", Val = "2" }, 
                new Demo { Name = "Third" } 
            };

        // Obviously this will blow up as my last item in 'list' has a null 'Val' property
        try {
            List<Test> results = list.Select(l => new Test { Name = l.Name, Val = int.Parse(l.Val) }).ToList();
        } 
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            // I want some generic way of capturing a better fault here in my log - e.g. more details about the actual item in my collection would be useful!
            Log.Error("Something broke", x, this);
        }

    }
}
```

[Link to codepen example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oajYTY)

The code above would likely log an exception such as:

> Run-time exception (line 48): Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   String
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   String]   at Program.b__5(Demo l): line 48   at Program.Main():
>   line 48

So I know I can capture `x.Message`, stack trace etc, but my point is that when working with large / complex data sets (especially when data comes from another system in production environment etc.) it can be difficult to track down the actual piece of data / item in the collection which is causing the exception.

Is there a neat / generic (no pun intended) way of handling this type of scenario?

Comment: Do you mean: "when using *lambda expressions*?". I see one generic argument in your example, but it doesn't seem to have to do with the problem you're facing.

Comment: @Ocelot20 yes - question updated for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. If your *weren't* using Linq, you would have code similar to:

```
public List<Test> DemoToTestProjection(List<Demo> demos)
{
    var projectedTests = new List<Test>();

    for each (var demo in demos)
    {
        projectedTests.Add(new Test
        {
            Name = l.Name,
            Val = int.Parse(l.Val)
        });
    }

    return projectedTests;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    var demos = new List<Demo>({...});

    try
    {
        var result = DemoToTestProjection(demos);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // How would you expect to get information about the specific
        // `Demo` you were having an issue with here?
    }
}
```

The answer is that you would need to put the try/catch around the location you wanted the detailed logging for.

So if you want that level of logging, you could do it by creating a different method to do the projection, and add your logging there:

```
var = list.Select(l => MapToTest(l))
          .ToList();

public Test MapToTest(Demo demo)
{
    try
    {
        Test test = new Test {...};
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogStuffAboutDemo(demo);
    }
}
```

Or (uglier), inline:

```
var = list.Select(l =>
          {
              try {...}
              catch{ LogStuffAboutDemo(l); }
          })
          .ToList();
```